# How to make a Label to display out of the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Since the ToolTip doesn't do what I need, I created my own based on a Label using C#. My problem is when my tooltip is too big, the Label is cut by the Form. The Label displays in the form and not on top of the form.

Can I make a Label to display on top of the Form to allow it to be bigger than the Form and see the entire Label?
If yes how!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to just use a separate form and place the new form (with your label) on top of the existing form.

Optionally, you could handle the [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged.aspx) event of the Label and expand your form to be greater than or equal to the size of the Label.